# Why we cannot apply the guarantee included in JLS?

Tags: java, memory-model

I got a mail from [*mailing list*](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Epugh/java/memoryModel/) which says that if actions on volatile vars contain data race then guarantee("A program is correctly synchronized if and only if all sequentially consistent executions are free of data races." in [*JLS*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)) can not be applied.

For convenience, I just put part of [*orginal content*](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Epugh/java/memoryModel/archive/2477.html) at here:

> I have a program that uses volatile variables and I am trying to reason about it using the "A program is correctly synchronized if and only if all sequentially consistent executions are free of data races." guarantee in JLS3.
>
> JLS3 seems to contain a glitch that prevents me from proving that my program is free of data races. Specifically, consider a read R of a volatile variable V and a write W of V that comes after R in the synchronization order. JLS3 seems to consider R and W to be conflicting accesses. Moreover,
> there is no happens-before edge from R to W (and rightly so). Therefore,JLS3 seems to also consider R and W to constitute a data race. Finally, it seems therefore that I cannot apply the above mentioned guarantee.

So this is my question: Why we cannot apply the guarantee included in JLS if actions on volatile vars contain data race?

Comment: It's not a guarantee, it's a definition, and it specifically excludes the condition you have described. Not a real question.

Comment: The answer is given [in this message](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/archive/2482.html) => there is a bug in the definition of a data race which allows this but it should not be the case (i.e. using volatile variables should prevent data races, but it is not always the case with the current JMM wording).

Comment: @assylias Confusingly, this fact is already well known to OP.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Then I don't understand why he is asking if he already knows the answer (unless he needed the proof you gave).

Comment: @assylias Exactly, that's the confusing bit. I have explained every possible angle to this (and quite a bit more) in the answer to his previous question.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik By the way did you find out why this "bug" was not fixed in JLS 7, since it was spotted well before it was released?

Comment: @assylias The best I could find was that there are "greater issues" to take care of so nobody bothers to touch the spec just to correct this "minor" bug. Of course, whenever you touch anything, you risk introducing new problems, so nobody is rushing into it. BTW not only was it spotted well before the 7 release, it was spotted basically right away when te 3rd edition came out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequentially consistent execution contains a read of volatile preceding a write to a volatile

=>

the execution contains a data race

=>

the program is not "correctly synchronized"

=>

the JLS does not give the guarantees that apply to correctly synchronized programs.

Comment: Marko Topolnik, thanks for your answer. I don't know whether my understanding is correct or not, if it is not, please correct it: 
becuase "A program that only shares volatile vars between threads cannot possibly contain a data race", "A sequentially consistent execution (of such program) contains a read of volatile preceding a write to a volatile" is still a execution of correctly synchronized program, but according to current definition of data race,"the execution contains a data race", so "the program is not 'correctly synchronized'".

Comment: Because according to above mentioned guarantee and current definition of data race, we can get a contradicted conclusion, "it seems therefore that I cannot apply the above mentioned guarantee."

Comment: There is no contradiction involved, but a clash between the **spirit** and the **letter**: the *letter* says that the program sharing volatile vars is **incorrectly synchronized**; the *spirit* makes it obvious that it is **correctly synchronized**.

Comment: Clash is also a contradiction, right? Thanks for your reply. To resolve this problem, I also have a suggestion, but I just don't know whether it is feasible: adding a new item into definition of happens-before relationship: If x and y are synchronization actions and x comes before y in synchronization order, then hb(x, y). So what's your opinion about it?

Comment: No, the way I used "clash" is unrealated to the logical term "contradiction". It's as if you had a fully consistent formal number system where 1+1=3. The clash only exists between the system and the part of the world that it is supposed to model, but fails.

Comment: Your suggestion would result in too much unnecessary ordering, like "read b", "write a". Even if you restricted it to just the case that "read a" hb "write a", by transitivity this would still be too heavy. Data races are all about access of non-volatile vars and that's what the definition must reflect.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your reply.